# getting warning while calculating difference in age?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am getting waring while calculating difference in age

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/1wIvVISmgEqcRNnAD971?p=preview

> moment.min.js:1 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a
>   recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js
>   Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non
>   RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an
>   upcoming major release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments:  [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false,
>   _l: undefined, _i: 09-Feb-1983, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object] Error
>       at Function.createFromInputFallback (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js:1:3368)
>       at Yt (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js:1:21353)
>       at Ot (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js:1:22064)
>       at Tt (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js:1:22146)
>       at Nt (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js:1:24464)
>       at M.ln.diff (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js:1:29987)
>       at Object. (http://run.plnkr.co/rVHCD6iVYofYv9Th/app.js:8:22)
>       at Object.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js:4570:17)
>       at extend.instance (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js:9435:34)
>       at nodeLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js:8540:34

I am doing like this

```
let DOB= "09-Feb-1983"
console.log(moment(DOB, 'DD-MMM-YYYY', true).isValid())
console.log(moment().format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
console.log(moment().diff('09-Feb-1983', 'years'))
```

how to remove this warning I already specify the format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could cast the string to a moment before passing it into the `diff()` function.

try like this

```
let DOB= "09-Feb-1983"
console.log(moment(DOB, 'DD-MMM-YYYY', true).isValid())
console.log(moment().format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
console.log(moment().diff(moment('09-Feb-1983', 'DD-MMM-YYYY'), 'years'));
```